# How to improve performance of many appends to a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, postgresql, async-await, aiopg

How to improve a performance of the following code?

```
BANNED_DOORBOTS = {...}

async def execute_query(self, query):
    async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(query)
            records = []
            async for row in cur:
                if row[0] not in BANNED_DOORBOTS:
                    records.append({
                        'key1': row[0],
                        'key2': row[1]
                    })

    return records
```

I don't want to check each time `if row[0] not in BANNED_DOORBOTS`.
How to avoid this?

Usually, I have more than hundred (up to 20 000) elements in `records`. Maybe I can pre-allocate some space to avoid reallocations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are rebuilding a list each time, from a database query.

I'd ask the *database* to not return records that are banned:

```
from psycopg2 import sql  # safe SQL composing

# Add a NOT IN clause to filter out banned doorbots, generating a
# separate parameter placeholder per value
query = sql.SQL(query) + sql.SQL(' WHERE ding_id NOT IN ({})').format(
    sql.SQL(', ').join([sql.Placeholder()] * len(BANNED_DOORBOTS)))
await cur.execute(query, BANNED_DOORBOTS)
```

I used the [`psycopg.sql` framework](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) to do the compositing here, but you could get away with string formatting too (use `'%s'` for placeholders).

Consider putting the `BANNED_DOORBOTS` set in a table in the database instead so you can use a `WHERE ding_id NOT IN (SELECT id from BANNED_DOORBOTS WHERE id IS NOT NULL)` subquery. That way you get better performance still (the database can optimise for this), and you don't have to generate placeholders.

Next, use a list comprehension to build the list. This is faster because it avoids repeated `list.append` lookups and method calls. Define your column names as a tuple and zip that together with each row:

```
keys = ('ding_id', 'doorbot_id', 'created_at', 'address', 'latitude', 
        'longitude', 'ding_kind')
return [dict(zip(keys, row)) async for row in cur]
```

The `async for` list comprehension syntax requires Python 3.6 or newer.

The `aiopg` driver lets you configure an alternative cursor factory, one that [already produces dictionaries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor), which may be faster still. You then don't have to use any list comprehension at all:

```
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

# configure cursor to yield dictionaries rather than tuples
async with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) as cur:
    await cur.execute(query, BANNED_DOORBOTS)
    # directly return the cursor; have the caller do the async iteration
    return cur
```

If you don't want to make the caller responsible for looping, but *have* to produce a list, use the [`cursor.fetchall()` method](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core.html#aiopg.Cursor.fetchall) to produce that list; each element will be a dictionary:

```
# configure cursor to yield dictionaries rather than tuples
async with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) as cur:
    await cur.execute(query, BANNED_DOORBOTS)
    return await cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could you please provide a full code of the algorithm with list comprehension, because I'm new in python and don't really understand what the final version will be (with `return [dict(zip(keys, row)) ...]`)

Comment: @ipetr: replace everything from `records = []` onwards. So the `return [...]` is inside the `with asyc ...` context managers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I completely understand how to do this. I will be very grateful if you paste a full code at the end of your answer

Comment: @ipetr: thing is, I offered several different alternatives; picking just one for a complete example would make things rather messy. Personally, I'd skip the comprehension altogether and go for the `RealDictRow` cursor factory here, and return the `cur` cursor directly, which is shown in the last example. In that example, the `return cur` is located in the same place as the list comprehension would go. Replace that line with the `keys = ...` and `return [...]` lines, same indentation.

Comment: @ipetr: the `async with conn.cursor(...):` context manager sets up a cursor for you; everything you do that needs access to the cursor is nested inside it. Since the `return [... for row in cur]` code uses the cursor, you indent it do be inside the context manager.

Comment: @ipetr: I also added another option: using a dictionary cursor factory and returning a list (no list comprehension needed).